# importance in temporary table creation on procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

What is the purpose of creating temporary table while processing very long procedures?

I was just tried simple procedure to insert values in temporary table,
can anyone explain importance of creating temporary table?

```
create procedure uspinsert 
as
begin 
select *from tbl_Sample
end

create table #tbl_new
(col1 int,
col2 varchar(20))
insert #tbl_new exec uspinsert
```

In this simple way I tried. While tuning, saw many temporary table creation in development side.

Does it improve performance?

Comment: Depends what you're doing, and what DB you're using. You may be able to accomplish the same thing with table variables or CTEs. Or in DBs if you want to return a table of results from a procedure it's simplest to throw them in a temporary table. Or if you need to pass data between procedures that's often easiest with a temp table too.

Comment: for improving query performance collecting ideas, am using sql server 2008 R2..

Comment: As a way of avoiding repeating work then, perhaps, or breaking up a bad query plan you really can't affect any other way. But I'd be surprised if they were that useful for performance - instead you probably want to look at index usage and the individual clauses in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

the imortance of temporary table is effectively in performance. Once again we fall in the case of Space VS Time. To reduce the processing time we create temporary table that holds the data we need ordered in the way we need it. So for all action you perform on the items in that temporary table, it will take you less time